# PrimeNG tree component

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-tree

I should make a Primeng tree. This is my model.

```
export interface Profiles {
  active?: true,
  description?: string,
  function?: [
    string
  ],
  id?: number,
  macroFunction?: string,
  name?: string,
  nodeTree?: [
    {
      children?: [
        string
      ],
      data?: {
        description?: string,
        flag?: true,
        functionFK?: string,
        id?: number,
        order?: number,
        parent?: number
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know how to do the http call and the rest.

I thought about something like that:
service:

```
 postProfiles(): Promise<Profiles > {
    const url = 'profiles/create';
    return this.http.post<Profiles >(url, {})
      .toPromise()
  }
```

ts --> http

```
node: Profile[];
selectedNode: Profile;
    ngOnInit() {
            this.nodeService.postProfiles().then(node=> this.selectedNode= node);
        }
```

HTML

```
<p-tree [value]="node" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode"></p-tree>
```

Can someone help me? What's wrong?
Thanks in advance!

**Done! I hope it'll be useful**

```
node:any; 

this.ricercaService.getTree().subscribe( (res) => { 
this.node = res.nodeTree; 
}, 
(error) => { c
onsole.log(error); 
});
```

HTML –

```
<p-tree *ngIf="node" [value]="node" selectionMode="checkbox" [(selection)]="selectedNode"> <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default"> <b>{{ node.data.description }}</b> </ng-template> </p-tree> –
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code :

- You don't set your `node` property in your component class ;
- Your data don't match the required shape [defined by the PrimeNG tree component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tree) (property `value`) ;

Here are some fixes

- Service :

  ```
  // It's better to keep using Observable instead of Promise as it is more flexible and powerful
  // and shareReplay() avoid requesting your server again if subscribed multiple times
  postProfiles(): Observable<Profiles[]> {
      const url = 'profiles/create';
      return this.http.post<Profiles[]>(url, {}).pipe(shareReplay());
  }
  ```
- Component :

  ```
   // This is your profiles transformed into TreeNode from PrimeNG
   nodes$: Observable<TreeNode[]>;
   selectedNode: TreeNode;

   ngOnInit() {
       // Here we map each Profile into TreeNode
       this.nodes$ = this.nodeService.postProfiles().pipe(
           map(profiles => profiles.map(p => ({
               label: p.name,
               children: p?.nodeTree?.children.map(child => ({
                   label: child.label
               })
           })
       );
   }
  ```
- Template (HTML) :

  ```
   <!-- The "| async" subscribe to this observable and use the value received -->
   <p-tree [value]="nodes | async" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode"></p-tree>
  ```

Comment: Done! I wrote the solution above